# How to enable multiple users to select different records from same table using MS Access front-end and MariaDB?

Tags: vba, ms-access, mariadb, ado, dao

I have Microsoft Access front-end and MariaDB database. For example lets assume that there is only one table in database. I would like to enable that users can select some records using checkbox column to perform some operation on them. I could just add column 'check' to that table, but if I use connected recordset then particular record is marked for all users as well. If I use disconnected recordset than it is not editable.

What would be best approach to gain that functionality?

I am familiar with both DAO and ADO recordsets so either approach would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use a multi-select listbox. When ready, build a list of the IDs of the selected rows and open the editing form having a recordsource like this:

```
Select * From YourTable Where ID In (2,5,7,9,22)
```

Alternatively, fill a temp table including a checkbox, and let the user check records as needed, then - as above or using an inner join - filter the true table.

Comment: Your alternative suggestion is more appropriate for me. Actually, it is just what I started to do. I just need to figure out why I can't get editable recordset inner joining temp and true table. Both with primary keys.

Comment: Either you miss a primary index - or use an outer join to a query holding the temp table filtered for checkbox = True.